# How can I use the Edmonds & Karp Algorithm for residual graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, deep-residual-networks, edmonds-karp

I am on to solve the Edmonds and Karp Algorithm. On normal Networks I know how to use it, indeed I am unsure / I got no clue how to use the Algorithm on a residual graph, hence there are Back-Edges.

Can anyone tell me, how an iteration is done there?

Answer (score 0):

Edmonds & Karp algorithm will work on both "normal network" and "residual graph" as long as you initialize the input graph properly at the start i.e. just make sure to initialize the back-edges and the corresponding flow amounts correctly.